# How can I manage display and spacing on a Crystal Report where I have to display images between the text field?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field that I'm displaying on a report that is a combination of text and codes that represent an image. Some of those icons have ascii symbols that I've used a replace formula to display them as their ascii version. For two or three of the images, I have no luck and have to display a mini picture for the representation.

The codes being sent are something like:

`^he^ = ♥   ^st^ = ⭐   ^cl^ =    etc...`

So for the clover leaf, there is no emoji support in my version of Crystal for clover leaves, and the ascii icon I found online for it just shows the empty square icon when an emoji isn't supported.

My workaround for this is to have a formula that converts all my icons to the appropriate ascii where supported, and to leave two blank spaces for the unsupported icons.

```
>stringvar gift_msg;

>gift_msg:= {DataTable1.gift_field};

>gift_msg := replace(gift_msg,"^CL^","  ");
>gift_msg := replace(gift_msg,"^HE^","♥");
>gift_msg := replace(gift_msg,"^ST^","★");

>gift_msg
```

I then put a suppression formula on each image that looks like this:

```
>mid({DataTable1.gift_field},2,4)<>"^CL^"
```

So I duplicated the image along the length of the field and increment the mid formula to match the field. I also set the font to Consolas so that it's fixed width to remove any surprises in spacing. My issue is that this still creates very strange spacing, and I'm almost certain there's a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a free service such as Calligraphr.com to convert your image to a font.

Comment: Ok I actually used emojis to show the example, but the images I'm using are all black and white. Thanks for the suggestion; will try and see if it works (have had some issues with fonts when deployed from a server, so let's see how it goes).

Comment: I created a custom font as suggested and mapped each image that I needed to a character that wouldn't be used. I then added that character to my replace formula that I mentioned above and set the font as my new font, but it just prints my mapping code instead of the image. I tested the font in Word, and it really does display the image when I add the correct mapping character. I also tried to display only one of the characters in a textbox to see if maybe the formula was the issue, but same result; prints the mapping code instead of image.

Comment: Did you install the custom font on the machine displaying the Crystal report?
Did you set the Crystal formula's font to that new font?

Comment: If you need to assign different fonts to different portions of the text, instead of concatenating the portions into a single formula, drag the different portions into a single text object.

Comment: Yes, installed on the server and also my local PC. In order to just test the font, I tried to just have a text object with one of the characters from the font and see if it displayed properly and it still displayed the code I mapped instead of the image.

Comment: okay I just tried to use 0, 1, 2 instead of foreign currency symbols as the mapping, and it does show up in Crystal designer now, but still isn't being converted to the image from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your image relies on several colors, the font option might not work.

Another option is to build the expression as html with image source directives where you need them. You would then need a create or use a 3rd-party UFL to convert the full expression to an image that you can load on the fly using the Graphic Location expression.  At least one of the UFLs listed by Ken Hamady [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provides such a function.